# XAML bind to Collection[index].ObjectProperty

Tags: xaml, binding

I have an observable collection of objects in my VM. I want to bind to a property of a specific item in the list in a text block, something like this:

```
Binding="{MyVMCollection[0].Description}"
```

But this syntax does not work. Is it possible to do what I am after and if so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the `Binding` keyword and I think you also need to use `Path`.

```
Binding="{Binding Path=MyVMCollection[0].Description}"
```

Comment: Yeah I have the Binding sorry, just typed that in a hurry. I will try your syntax with Path and see what happens, thanks!

Comment: Assuming your `DataContext` contains an object which has `MyVMCollection` as a property, you would use it exactly as I wrote it.  If your `DataContext` _is_ `MyVMCollection` then you would have to do `Path=[0].Description` (I think).

Answer (score 1):

The type of the object needs to be a type where an array index would normally work for this to work. I'm not sure the exact constraints but use `Type[]` if in doubt.

eg. If it is some weird enumerable type like `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` (or some wierd LINQy type) then something like `{Binding List[0]}` won't work.